# Can I query a publication list for data extension members?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

is it possible to query a publication list but pull data only for members that exist on a specific data extension? The data I need exists in the publication list (created date and status), but I only want the data for members of a specific data extension, not the entire publication list. This is what I started with, but it's not limiting it to the data extension members. I know I need to add something that tells it I only want those that exist in the data extension, but I don't know how to do that:

```
SELECT
L.CreatedDate
,L.EmailAddress
,L.ListID
,L.Status
FROM ent._ListSubscribers L
left join ENT."data extension name" S on L.EmailAddress = S.Email_Address
where l.ListID   =  List ID Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to start with your Data Extension and use an [**inner join**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) back to `_ListSubscribers`:

```
select
  l.createddate
, l.emailaddress
, l.listid
, l.status
from ent.DataextEnsionName s
inner join ent._listsubscribers l on (l.emailaddress = s.email_address)
where l.listid = 12345
```